# On change select to button

Tags: php, wordpress, post, radio-button, onchange

I use onchange select on my WP website to query post. I want to change select by radio button or checkbox but I don't know how do that...

My actualy code

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option class="etistyle"></option>
<option class="etistyle" value="?order=?" method="POST">Nouveautés</option>
<option class="etistyle" value="?tri=prix&order=asc" method="POST">Moins cher</option>
<option class="etistyle" value="?tri=prix&order=desc" method="POST">Plus cher</option>
</select>
```

and

```
    <?php $tripname = $_GET['order'];?>
                 <?php if ($tripname == "desc") :?>
                    <a href="<?php $current_url = 'http://';
                        $current_url .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // Get host
                        $path = explode( '?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); // Blow up URI
                        $current_url .= $path[0]; // Only use the rest of URL - before any parameters
                        echo $current_url;?>">Plus cher<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <?php endif;?>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
    <input type="radio" method="POST" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" value="?tri=prix&order=asc" />
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Inputs have no method, forms do.

Comment: ok so what can i do ? I m lost :'(

Comment: Nobody have idea ??